# ORACLE - Enable Unique constraint issue (same constraint name, multiple schemas)

Tags: sql, oracle, unique-constraint, alter-table

I'm having an issue trying to re-enable a unique constraint. I try using this command:

```
alter table TESTSCHEMA_1.TEST_TABLE1 enable constraint TEST_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT1;
```

The issue is that i have multiple schemas (say: TESTSCHEMA_1 to _5), and they all have tables with the same name TEST_TABLE1 which also have a Unique constraint with the same name TEST_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT1.

As a result I get this error:

> ORA-02299: cannot validate (TESTSCHEMA_1.TEST_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT1) - duplicate keys found

How can I indicate specifically the schema where is the constraint i want to enable?  I've tried using TESTSCHEMA_1.TEST_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT1, but it throws a syntax error (Non-properly ended sql command)

Comment: Do you want to remove the existing duplicates?

Comment: Did you check for duplicate keys? The error message seems to be telling you to resolve duplicate keys before the dbms can apply a unique constraint.

Comment: As for your last question, you are already specifying the schema by putting `TESTSCHEMA_1` in front of the table name. The constraint will reside in the same schema as its parent table so you don't need to (and can't) specify it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check uniqueness of your data.

```
select unique_column_in_test_table1, count(unique_column_in_test_table1) from TESTSCHEMA_1.TEST_TABLE1
group by unique_column_in_test_table1
having count(unique_column_in_test_table1) > 1
```

if any rows return by this query you have to handle/correct it to be unique.

Comment: I see, when i got the error i thought the issue was because of the multiple schemas having unique constraints with the same name, but it is in the data within the constraint. Thank you :)